# Path in Web.config

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-config

In web.config file iam using path like this

```
D:\\folder1\\folder\\folder\\folder\\folder\\folder\\folder\\
```

but in my page iam getting D:folder folder ....like this

please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Try using \\ or /

Also: why not using a relative path instead of absolute?